# Inserting period at the end of references (natbib/dinat)

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

Using the style `dinat` for the package `natbib`, the references in the bibliography do not have a period `.`  at the end.

How do I add it?

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `dinat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say `dinat-mod.bst`.
- Open the file `dinat-mod.bst` in a text editor. The editor you employ for your tex files will do fine.
- In the file, locate the function `out.bibitem.end`. In my copy of the file, this function starts at line 522.
- Add the instruction `add.period$` at the start of the function. It should then look like this:

  ```
  FUNCTION {out.bibitem.end}
  % end of entry
  { add.period$
    write$
    newline$
  }
  ```
- Save the file `dinat-mod.bst` either in a directory that's searched by BibTeX or in the directory where your main tex file is located. If you choose the former option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{dinat}` to `\bibliographystye{dinat-mod}`. Then, run a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{aa,author="Anne Author",title="Thoughts",year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dinat-mod}

\begin{document}
\cite{aa}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```